# ERROR: libsmartredis failed to build and install

Tags: makefile, redis, redisclient, smartsim

```
cd $ROOTDIR
git clone https://github.com/CrayLabs/SmartRedis.git
cd SmartRedis
git checkout v0.2.0
make lib -j
export SMARTREDIS_DIR=$(pwd)
```

I am trying to execute the above commands to install SmartRedis (SmartSim Infrastructure Library Clients). But I am getting the following error when **make lib -j** is executed:

```
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/smartredisPy.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/smartredisPy.dir/src/python/src/pyclient.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/smartredisPy.dir/build.make:328: CMakeFiles/smartredisPy.dir/src/python/bindings/bind.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:156: CMakeFiles/smartredisPy.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
ERROR: libsmartredis failed to build and install
make: *** [Makefile:29: lib] Error 1
```

If more details are necessary please let me know.